# Loop specific number of rows in While loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy every 20 lines in the current sheet into a new workbook.

Getting an error in the while loop.

> Runtime Error 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error"

```vb
Sub OpenAndSaveNewBook()
    Dim MyBook As Workbook, newBook As Workbook
    Dim FileNm As String
    Dim i As Integer
    i = 0
    Set MyBook = ThisWorkbook
    While (Rows(i) <> "")   
        FileNm = "E:\" & "NEW-BOOK" & i & ".xls"
        Set newBook = Workbooks.Add

        With newBook
            MyBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(i & ":" & (i + 20)).Copy .Sheets("Sheet1").Rows("1")

            'Save new wb with XLS extension
            .SaveAs Filename:=FileNm, FileFormat:=xlNormal, CreateBackup:=False

            .Close Savechanges:=False
        End With
        i = i + 21
    
    Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: What does the debugger tell you when you step through the code?

Comment: What line is throwing the error?

Comment: You can't have a row(0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Export Rows

```vb
Sub ExportRows()
    
    ' Constants
    
    Const SRC_FIRST_ROW As Long = 1 ' row of the used range
    Const DST_FIRST_ROW As Long = 1 ' worksheet row
    Const DST_ROWS_COUNT As Long = 20
    
    ' Source
    
    Dim swb As Workbook: Set swb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = swb.Sheets("Sheet1")
    
    Dim sfrrg As Range, srCount As Long
    
    With sws.UsedRange.EntireRow
        Set sfrrg = .Rows(SRC_FIRST_ROW)
        srCount = .Rows.Count + .Row - SRC_FIRST_ROW
        If srCount < 1 Then
            MsgBox "Not enough rows.", vbCritical
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End With
    
    ' Destination
    
    ' Counts
    Dim drCount As Long: drCount = DST_ROWS_COUNT
    Dim dwCount As Long: dwCount = Int(srCount / drCount)

    Dim ldrCount As Long: ldrCount = srCount Mod drCount ' remainder
    If ldrCount > 0 Then dwCount = dwCount + 1
    
    ' Export
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    Dim dwb As Workbook, dw As Long, dFileName As String
    
    For dw = 1 To dwCount
        ' Remainder
        If dw = dwCount Then
            If ldrCount > 0 Then drCount = ldrCount
        End If
        ' Copy
        Set dwb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet) ' single worksheet
        sfrrg.Resize(drCount).Copy dwb.Sheets(1).Rows(DST_FIRST_ROW)
        Set sfrrg = sfrrg.Offset(DST_ROWS_COUNT)
        ' Save & Close
        dFileName = "E:\" & "NEW-BOOK" & (dw - 1) * DST_ROWS_COUNT + 1 & ".xls"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False ' overwrite without confirmation
            dwb.SaveAs dFileName, xlNormal
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        dwb.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Next dw
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Rows exported.", vbInformation

End Sub
```